# VBA HTTP GET request - cookies with colons

Tags: vba, serverxmlhttp

I am trying to send an HTTP GET request in VBA which includes a cookie containing a colon character, like so:

```
objReq.Open "GET", "http://my.url.com?foo=bar", False
objReq.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "abcd=cookie:containing:colons"
objReq.Send
```

Depending on what object type I use for `objReq`, however the request gets treated differently.

The following object type works:

```
Dim objReq As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set objReq = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
```

Unfortunately, I need to use a different object type (as `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` can't capture sufficient detail about HTTP redirects).  From what I've read, I need to use `Winhttp.WinHttpRequest`, `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP40`, or `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60`, but using any of those objects results in the following error when including colons in the cookie value.

[image]

I have tried replacing the colons with `Chr(58)`, `%3A`, and double-quoting within the string to no avail.  I have also tried adding a 'Content-Type' header with various character encodings, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Anyone know how I can send a cookie value containing colons using the `Winhttp.WinHttpRequest`, `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP40`, or `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` objects?

PS: Alternatively, if anyone knows how I can get the ending URL of a redirect sequence when using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`, that would work as well! `Winhttp.WinHttpRequest` would allow me to capture a 302 status code, and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP40` or `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60` would allow me to use `GetOption(-1)`, but `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` doesn't support either of these methods (from what I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of testing with WinHttpRequest and I came up with the following code:

```
Dim objReq As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Set objReq = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
objReq.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
objReq.Open "GET", "http://www.example.com", False
objReq.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "abcd=cookie:containing:colons"
objReq.send
```

I did notice i got the same error that you posted when I forgot to include the "http://" in the url.

I hope this helps!